# Implement Express Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a *Nodejs* server with router files that take absolute routes for the `HTTP methods`, for example `/api/users/all`.

```js
// /routes/user.routes.js

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.get(
    "/api/users/all",
    controller.allAccess
  );
}
```

Which I `require()` in my *server.js* file like this.

```js
// server.js

require("./routes/user.routes")(app);
```

Now, instead of using the absolute routes, I would like to implement `express.Router()`.

I made the following changes in my *user.routes.js* file.

```js
// /routes/user.routes.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  router.get(
    "/all",
    controller.allAccess
  );
}
```

I created an *index.js* file in my *routes* folder that uses the routes and `exports` the `router`.

```js
// /routes/index.js

const express = require("express");
const userRoutes = require("./user.routes");

const router = express.Router();
router.use("/users", userRoutes);

module.exports = router;
```

And made the following changes in my *server.js* file.

```js
// server.js

const routes = require("./routes");
app.use("/api/v1", routes);
```

But I am getting error messages when hitting the route.

> TypeError: app.use is not a function at module.exports

What should I do to implement `express.Router()` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside your `/routes/user.routes.js` because app variable is undefined in there. To fix the issue you need to replace `app` with `router` variable like below:

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
router.get("/all", controller.allAccess);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem, how could I pass app with my router?

Comment: I got rid of the function and am just exporting the router at the end of all methods, your answer lead me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Could you maybe update your answer to `const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
});


router.get(
    "/all",
    controller.allAccess
); module.exports = router;` that way if anyone needs it, it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Did you just forget to pass the `app` into your `router.use("/users", userRoutes);` call?

At the moment `user.routes` doesn't know what `app` is because you haven't implemented something like `const app = express();`and need to pass it in instead.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: Would this work?

`
//index.js
const express = require("express");
const userRoutes = require("./user.routes");

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.use("/users", userRoutes(app));

module.exports = router;
`

Comment: That is not working, could I pass it in the server.js file?

Comment: I fixed the problem, I am not exporting a function anymore, just the router, thank you for your help!